# PS3 games that fully supports move

Tags: playstation-move

Where can I find an updated list of Sony Playstation 3 games that fully supports Move.

With fully I mean games that has been developed with Move in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Going to [Sony's Move site](http://us.playstation.com/ps3/playstation-move/games/) and filtering (near bottom of the screen) to only show games with `Move Required` (and not `Move compatible`), should give a fairly good list.

Only problem is that it seems to be only SCEE games... So does Sony only promote their Move-only games or are they the only ones available as of today? I didn't find non-Sony Move-only games on Amazon, so it *seems* the latter is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia has special category for PlayStation Move-only games. The list is available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:PlayStation_Move-only_games).

Apparently, at this moment almost all games come from SCEE, though I skimmed through the list and found one 3rd party title - Time Crisis: Razing Storm from Namco.

Answer (score 0):

This playstation blog site posting has links to all the games in the list.  This is the one I'm using to decide if I want the Move  :)  : [here](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2010/12/17/playstation-move-approaching-50-supported-games-more-to-come/)